# Cordova/PhoneGap CLI "prepare" removes platform assets added by "plagman"

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

When I install an Android specific plugin using `plugman` it adds asset files to `platforms/android/asstes/www/` which is cleared on every `cordova prepare` cli command and I have to manually add them back.

Is there any way to make plugman to copy them to `merges/android/` or `platforms/android/platform_www/` instead so that I don't need to copy them manually after every prepare?

Comment: Why do you need to use plugman?  Can you just use "cordova plugin" instead?

Comment: @mooreds I have read somewhere that for platform specific plugins it is better to use plugman, is that right? I'm trying to install: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas

Comment: I don't think you need to use plugman for platform specific plugins.  There are some cases where you might want to use plugman (if there's a bugfix in the latest version of plugman that hasn't made it into your version of cordova cli, for instance) but in general, I've had success using cordova cli only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have very specific needs (you don't want to use the CLI at all, or you need a bugfix or feature in a version of plugman that is incompatible with your version of cordova CLI), the best way to install all plugins in cordova is via the CLI:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas
```

The CLI uses plugman under the covers, but handles different asset directories, etc.

You can install plugins that are android only or ios only with cordova plugins.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I add it only to Android?

Comment: I think the easiest way to do that is to only put an android platform element: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/plugin_ref_spec.md#Plugin%20Specification_platform_element  Have never done this, though.  Please try and let us know.

Comment: Plugin files are added to all platforms but only loaded in Android.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the /merges folder with CLI:
1) install the plugin via plugman
2) copy the /plugins folder to /merges/android/yourplugin
3) next time you run "cordova prepare" or "cordova build" or "cordova run" it will keep that folder

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :: 
If you are using `phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas` on Cordova 3.0+ build will fail because of a few naming issues

I've proposed to the main git the fix and you can also find it on my fork `https://github.com/Davidx7/phonegap-plugin-fast-canvas`